# In a radio button, does the name or id get posted back?

Tags: asp.net, radio-button

My radio buttons are like this, there are 2 and whichever the person selects I want to get when the form posts.

A `<input type="radio" name="userType" id="a" />`

B `<input type="radio" name="userType" id="b"  />`

So I want to do:

`Request["userType"]`

and get 'a' or 'b'

**But I am getting 'on' returned from Request["userType"]**

Comment: Are you using WebForms or MVC?

Comment: you have almost 9k rep and don't know that you need to post code?

Comment: @Jason helpful... he might not do a lot of web dev

Comment: all the code is Request["userType"] and the html, what else is relevant here?

Comment: `id` is used as a selector for CSS and JavaScript on the client side, it's not part of form data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try giving each radio button a value

```
<input type="radio" name="userType" id="a" value="a" />

<input type="radio" name="userType" id="b" value="b" />
```